# Removing leading and trailing white spaces as well as leading zeroes

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to remove the leading zeroes 0011223344  and also leading and trailing white spaces

```
/^0+(?=[0-9]/
s/^\s+|\s+$//
```

How can I combine the two to get the same output.

```
11223344
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex in `perl`:

```
s/^\h*0*(?=\d)|\h+$
```

**RegEx Details**:

- `\h` matches a horizontal whitespace
- `^\h*0*(?=\d)`: At the start it will match 0 or more leading whitespaces followed by 0 or more leading zeroes as long as there is at least one digit ahead
- `|` OR
- `\h+$`: At the end it will match 1+ horizontal whitespaces

**Examples:**

```
perl -pe 's/^\h*0+(?=\d)|\h+$//g' <<< ' 001 '
1

perl -pe 's/^\h*0+(?=\d)|\h+$//g' <<< ' 000 '
0

perl -pe 's/^\h*0+(?=\d)|\h+$//g' <<< '     0000000123     '
123

perl -pe 's/^\h*0*(?=\d)|\h+$//g' <<< ' 123   '
123
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
s/^[\s0]+|\s+$//g
```

Or, for a corner case like `'  0000    '` where you would still like to keep one zero:

```
s/^(?:\s*(0)+\s*$|[\s0]+)|\s+$/$1/g
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/1WYDsM/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/1WYDsM/3).

**Details**

- `^[\s0]+` - matches one or more zeros or whitespace at the start of the string
- `^(?:\s*(0)+\s*$|[\s0]+)` - matches

  - `^` - start of string
  - `(?:\s*(0)+\s*$|[\s0]+)` - either of

    - `\s*(0)+\s*$` - 0+ whitespaces, 1 or more zeros each time captured  into Group 1, and then 0+ whitespaces till end of string
    - `|`- or
    - `[\s0]+` - 1 or more whitespaces or zeros
- `|` - or
- `\s+$` - matches one or more whitespace chars at the end of string.